# Receive whatsapp notification only between a certain time

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, tasker

I want to receive all WhatsApp messages only between 11-12 p.m everyday.How to do this? Can tasker app help in this.Or a script which can be used. Also please note that only messages should be queued but video/audio calls should function all day.

Comment: you can disable notifications for 1 Hour/1-day etc. through WhatsApp Web. Check more details at the official Whatsappp FAQ here https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/web/26000051/?category=5245251

Answer (score -1):

WhatsApp messages could not be stopped while they are coming from the app's data system.

> In other words, we can't stop WhatsApp from receiving new messages while we have an active internet connection.

One possible solution could be blocking the "New Messages" notifications coming from the WhatsApp application. Maybe, we will require some code to do this but it is yet possible.

> WhatsApp send notifications to alert the users regarding new messages. We could intercept these messages and block them for some time interval and also store them for later.

If the user can see notifications only in a specific interval of time, then we only know that new messages have arrived only at that specific time interval.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.But how to achieve this!!

Comment: You will need an app coded specifically to do this. Maybe, you can find one on the Play Store. This app might help -> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.mready.zenty

Comment: Can easily be done by intercepting the notifications during the desired timeframe with the AutoNotifications plugin, and making any action (such as 'dismiss') to achieve this.